# Not getting the wanted output in project with structs

Tags: arrays, c

**Given Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct charact
{
    char ch;
    int occurs;
    struct charact *next;
};
typedef struct charact Char;
typedef Char * ListofChar;
typedef Char * CharNode_ptr;
void letters(char name[50], ListofChar * chars_ptr);
void report(ListofChar chars);
Char * createnode(char ch);
int main(void)
{
    char name[50];
    ListofChar chars = NULL;
    scanf("%49s", name);
    letters(name, &chars);
    report(chars);
    return 0;
}
Char * createnode(char ch)
{
    CharNode_ptr newnode_ptr ;
    newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof (Char));
    newnode_ptr -> ch = ch;
    newnode_ptr -> occurs = 0;
    newnode_ptr -> next = NULL;
    return newnode_ptr;
}
void letters(char name[50], ListofChar * lst_ptr)
{
    /* add your code */
    return;
}
void report(ListofChar chars)
{
    /* add your code */
    return;
}
```

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct charact
{
    char ch;
    int occurs;
    struct charact *next;
};

typedef struct charact Char;
typedef Char * ListofChar;
typedef Char * CharNode_ptr;
void letters(char name[50], ListofChar * chars_ptr);
void report(ListofChar chars,int length);
void distance(char name[50],size_t size,Char *chars);
Char * createnode(char ch);

int main(void)
{
    char name[50];
    ListofChar chars = NULL;
    scanf("%49s", name);
    letters(name, &chars);
    report(chars,strlen(name));
    return 0;
}

Char * createnode(char ch)
{
    CharNode_ptr newnode_ptr ;
    newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof (Char));
    newnode_ptr -> ch = ch;
    newnode_ptr -> occurs = 0;
    newnode_ptr -> next = NULL;
    return newnode_ptr;
}

void letters(char name[50], ListofChar * lst_ptr)
{
    /* add your code */
    size_t i, j;
    j = strlen(name);
    memset(lst_ptr, 0, 50*sizeof (Char));


    for(i = 0; i < j; i++){
        distance(name, i, *lst_ptr);
    }
    return;
    }


void report(ListofChar chars,int length)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        printf("\n%c: %d", chars[i].ch, chars[i].occurs);
    }
    /* add your code */
    return;
}

void distance(char name[50],size_t size,Char *chars)
{
    int i,length;
    length = strlen(name);
    chars -> ch = name[size];

    for (i=size+1; i<length; i++)
    {
        if(name[i] == chars -> ch)
        {
            chars-> occurs = i - size;
            return;
        }
    }

    chars ->occurs=0;
    return;
}
```

I want this program to print the distance from the next repeated letter.
For example:   testing
**t:3
e:0
s:0
t:0
i:0
n:0
g:0**

Instead i get no output.Im new to C programming and im pretty average,this is a Uni project.I believe that the createnode function will be used in later versions of the project but im not sure.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind a typedef (`ListofChar`, `CharNode_ptr`).  Doing so makes it very difficult to track levels of indirection.

Comment: Consider not using `typedef` at all.  It is sometimes a convenience, but never a necessity, and it sometimes hurts more than it helps even when pointers are not involved.

Comment: This is was in the given code of the project

Comment: `memset(lst_ptr, 0, 50*sizeof (Char))` -- when you do that in `letters`, `lst_ptr` points to the  `chars` pointer from `main`, which is a single pointer, not 50 `Chars` items. That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I updated the post to the given code and the one that i have written

Comment: But you don't use the `createnode` function anywhere. You could of course solve the task with just the string, but I guess your teachers want you to create a linked list `t -> e -> s -> t`  and so on and then use that list to determine the distance to the next ocurrence.

Comment: linked lists will be used in a later version

Comment: "linked lists will be used in a later version" I strongly suspect that this is false, and your understanding of the assignment is incomplete.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: no ,it is specified in a later version.